# How to repair missing libs for Witcher 2 on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, 19.10

Here is the list of missing libs that popped up:
[image: missing libs]

 I have already tried other methods:
 `sudo apt install libc6:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-data:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsdl2-image-2.0-0:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libcurl3:i386`
 and i run out of ideas how to solve it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran Witcher 2 Enchanced from GOG. That was working for me. Ubuntu 20.04 / AMD Radeon RX570

first add i386 architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then install this list of packages as well:

```
sudo apt install libc6:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-data libasound2-plugins:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsdl2-image-2.0-0:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libcurl4:i386
```

It works :)